# VSelect should allow displaying selected items in order per :items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

VSelect preserves the order in which users select values (per the v-model), But we need them always in order per `:items`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row
          align="center"
        >
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-select
              v-model="value"
              :items="items"
              chips
              label="Chips"
              multiple
              hide-selected
              menu-props="auto"
            ></v-select>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I need the `value` should keep the order of `items`

if we choose `three`,`one`, and `four` in any order, the value must be `['one','three','four']`;

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    value: [],
  }),
})
```

see current behavior [here](https://codepen.io/prajin/pen/BaNVENp). I want the old behavior,Before [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4082) feature implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the list by filtering the original items array:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    value : []
  }),
  computed : {
    _value : {
      get () {
        return this.value
      },
      set (val) {
        this.value = this.items.filter(x=>val.includes(x))
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and update the v-model to the computed `_value`

```
<v-select v-model="_value"/>
```

https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/ZEGjWPW

Or using your template solution:

```
<v-select
 v-model="value"
 :items="items"  
 @change="value=items.filter(x=>value.includes(x))"
 attach
 chips
 label="Chips"
 multiple
 ></v-select>
```

Comment: No i don't want this, I have a better [solution](https://codepen.io/prajin-tst/pen/wvaxrzX) like this. But I want `value` must persist the order of `items`. This was the actual behavior before [this](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4082) feature implementation.

Comment: I understand now! Updated my answer

Comment: This is a game changer for someone who has never used the get() and set() methods of `computed`. It feels like dark magic and is quite the elegant solution. I regret to say that prior to finding this, I had a deep temptation to an infinite watcher loop...

Comment: This is a smell of bad design of the `vue-select`: do `filter`+ `includes` is reintroducing of the own logic of `vue-select`... Even more, this solution is insufficient to sort when you have `:reduce` prop on the `vue-select` component.